# Apply function on each column in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How I can write following function in more pandas way:

```
     def calculate_df_columns_mean(self, df):
        means = {}
        for column in df.columns.columns.tolist():
            cleaned_data = self.remove_outliers(df[column].tolist())
            means[column] = np.mean(cleaned_data)
        return means
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: what does `remove_outliers do?

Comment: Question why iterate over the columns and then do this: `cleaned_data = self.remove_outliers(df[column].tolist())`? this seems like you're removing the outliers repeatedly for all columns for every column?

Comment: I want to calculate the mean on clean data.

Comment: you can do: `clean_df.mean()`

Comment: You can calculate the mean for all the columns in one go and then remove the outliers in one go no? it seems to me that iterating over the columns is unnecessary here as you're removing the outliers on all columns and you can calculate the mean on the entire df

Comment: I agree with @EdChum - try to avoid `.apply()` method if possible, because it's pretty slow and ineffcient

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that the iteration over the columns is unnecessary:

```
def calculate_df_columns_mean(self, df):
    cleaned_data = self.remove_outliers(df[column].tolist())
    return cleaned_data.mean()
```

the above should be enough assuming that `remove_outliers` still returns a df

**EDIT**

I think the following should work:

```
def calculate_df_columns_mean(self, df):
    return df.apply(lambda x: remove_outliers(x.tolist()).mean()
```

Comment: remove_outliers gets list and returns clean list.

Comment: try my new edit, it should work but really you should focus on modifying `remove_outliers` to operate on a np array and if possible a `DataFrame` in a vectorised manner

Answer (score 5):

Use [`dataFrame.apply(func, axis=0)`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
# axis=0 means apply to columns; axis=1 to rows
df.apply(numpy.sum, axis=0) # equiv to df.sum(0)
```