# How can I search for anomalies in each column in a Dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, anomaly-detection

I have a Dataframe and my goal is to find anomalies for **each different column**. So I am looking for univariate anomalies.

Let's assume this is my Dataframe:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100, 6) * 1, columns=['A','B','C','D','E','F'])
```

I am faced with two questions:

1. Which algorithms are adequate for this goal? E.g. Isolation Forest?
2. How could I run an algorithm  (E.g. Isolation Forest) over all columns, rather than doing it column per column? Can I use  a for loop?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apply function on each column in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38848411/apply-function-on-each-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Not really. How would I use df.apply(function, axis=0) for anomaly detection?

Comment: You would have to run define a function that detect anomalies in a `pd.Series` (i.e., one column), and then run that on every column with `df.apply`

Comment: And this is what exceeds my knowledge. How would I define a function that detects anomalies?

Comment: One simple thing you could do is find values that are greater than 1.5 or 2 standard deviations from the mean. That's typically referred to as outlier detection.

Comment: Ok, can you tell me how I would code this function?

Comment: Can anyone help here?

Answer (score 2):

Q2:eg.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"bytes":[1,2,3,4,5], "flow":[1,2,3,4,5], "userid":[1,2,3,4,5]}).set_index("userid")

def get_anomaly(arr):
    # your algorithm
    if arr.bytes < 3 and arr.flow < 3:
        return -1
    elif arr.bytes > 3 and arr.flow > 3:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

df['is_anomaly'] = df.apply(get_anomaly, axis=1)

>>> df
   bytes  flow  userid  is_anomaly
0      1     1       1       -1
1      2     2       2       -1
2      3     3       3        0
3      4     4       4        1
4      5     5       5        1
```

We can talk a little bit about Q1.

Level 0: Linear relationships or other experiences

```
Box-plot: min outlier < Q1-1.5ΔQ <= normal data <= Q3+1.5ΔQ < max outlier

Scott rule: Δb=3.5σn1/3 .Split the data and do distribution statistics

Other data status: avg. mean std and so on.
```

Level 1: Statistical algorithm

```
Great algo: 
CMP
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1389128616301633

Beehive
https://nds2.ccs.neu.edu/papers/Beehive.pdf

CBLOF
https://www.goldiges.de/publications/Anomaly_Detection_Algorithms_for_RapidMiner.pdf

And some AR MA ARMA algo, I don't know much.
```

Level 2: Unsupervised learning

`Kmeans and so on...(This is actually quite a lot)`

Level 3: Supervised learning

```
from elasticsearch (doc)

EWMA  
s2=α*x2+(1-α)*s1

Holt-Linear  
s2=α*x2+(1-α)*(s1+t1)
t2=ß*(s2-s1)+(1-ß)*t1

Holt-Winters
si=α(xi-pi-k)+(1-α)(si-1+ti-1)
ti=ß(si-si-1)+(1-ß)ti-1
pi=γ(xi-si)+(1-γ)pi-k

from ML
CNN RNN LSTM Prefixspan AutoML Bayes and so on.(There are a few scenarios you can use.)
```

There are too many left unlisted, too many algorithms to use, too many appropriate, too many details to write down.
UEBA's thinking is important when analyzing anomalies.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I am going to study that. Questions number 2 is still unsolved, though.

Comment: @Minfetli Updated.